# Pip ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

*I can't use the pip command but python is installed properly.*

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\PERSONAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip3.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "c:\users\personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "c:\users\personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "c:\users\personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .util.ssl_ import (
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes```
````

Comment: Make sure the path to scripts folder for the python version is added to the path environment/system variable in order to use pip command directly without the whole path to pip.exe which is inside the scripts folder.

python -m pip install packagename
python -m pip uninstall packagename
python -m pip install --upgrade packagename

Also run as administrator!

Comment: already did that, but still not working. The path to the scripts is added as system variable but still when pip is entered, the above error message comes...